# How can I tell if a ManualResetEvent is signaled or non-signaled?

Tags: c#

I want to check to see if an instance of ManualResetEvent is signaled before starting a thread.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) with a timeout of zero. Either way, the function will return immediately and you can use the return value to determine whether the event was signalled or not.